# Understanding the Representation of Signal Variation by $\hat{u}^T T \hat{u}$ in the Context of 3D Orientation Tensors

Tags: tensors, orientation

I was studying the Gunnar Farneback method for [dense optical flow](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/905291) and encountered the following paragraph:

> By stacking the frames of an image sequence onto each
> other we obtain a spatiotemporal image volume with two
> spatial dimensions and a third temporal dimension. It is
> easy to see that movement in the image sequence induces
> structures with certain orientations in the volume. A trans-
> lating point, e.g., is transformed into a line whose direction
> in the volume directly corresponds to its velocity.
> A powerful representation of local orientation is the ori-
> entation tensor . In 3D this tensor takes the form of
> a $3 \times 3$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $T$ and the
> quadratic form $\hat{u}^T T \hat{u}$ can be interpreted as a measure of
> how much the signal locally varies in the direction given by
> $\hat{u}$.

My understanding of the 3D orientation tensor is that it is a rotation matrix in 3D world. Thus, it is a $3 \times 3$ matrix. But I don't understand how $\hat{u}^T T \hat{u}$ is derived and why $\hat{u}^T T \hat{u}$ can represent how much the signal locally varies in the direction given by
$\hat{u}$. Thank you.